# Displaying a .rtf file in an UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to display a .rft file which is download for my server.

I first used a UITextView, but I could see the text but there was a lot of encoding and strange character relating to colors and formatting also been shown.

Anyways searching here I found out that UITextView can not display rtf text properly.

So I moved on to trying a UIWebView which was supposed to be able to display .rft files, but alas its the same with lots of \pard\tx566\tx1133 type stuff appearing through out the file.

Is there something I am missing ?

I populate the UIWebView here

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
NSString *RadioGuideString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData 
encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[webview loadHTMLString:guideString baseURL:nil];
}
```

Code for setting up the UIWebView

```
    webview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 50, 310, 400)];
webview.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
[webview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];  
[webview setOpaque:NO];
[[self view] addSubview:webview];
```

Is there a special command I have missed?

Many Thanks
-Code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
NSURL *url = <create NSURL object pointing to your file>;
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:req];
```

Comment: I get the file from my server so its not saved locally. Is NSURLRequest useable in this instance?

Comment: Pick the best option for you to create your NSURL object with. The basic URLWithString should be ok. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 5):

If you have added the .rtf into the application then try this

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForAuxiliaryExecutable:@"<filename.extenssion>"];
NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filePath];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Comment: This works really well and is a nice simple solution. I recommend setting Scaling to Scales Page To Fit.