# RTF equivalent to UIWebView's loadHTMLString?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, xamarin.ios, rtf

Since OS 3.0 UIWebView supports [RTF files](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1630/_index.html).

If you have a .rtf file, it's easy enough to load it into a uiwebview, e.g.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:documentName ofType:nil];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

When loading HTML stored in a string variable, you can use `loadHTMLString`.

How would one load RTF stored in a string directly into a `UIWebView`? For example, if you have a string containing `{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1038\cocoasubrtf360
{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}.....`, using `loadHTMLString` will render it literally.

I would like to be able to render RTF from a string variable without having first to save it to a file.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778220/displaying-a-rtf-file-in-an-uiwebview ?

Comment: No, not a duplicate. I don't want to have to write RTF to a file first and then open it, I want to open it directly from a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `loadData:MIMEType:textEncodingName:baseURL:`. Haven't tried it, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The following code worked for me (MonoTouch): `myWebView.LoadData (rtfdata, "text/rtf", "utf-8", new NSUrl("/"));`.

Comment: With HTML, and PDF data, loadData:MIMEType:textEncodingName:baseURL: works fine with a nil baseURL.  For RTF I had to use
a base url of [NSURL URLWithString:@"/"]

Comment: Note @slangley comment - worked for me too, but _only_ if adding [NSURL URLWithString:@"/"]