# Display .RTF file on iOS devices WITHOUT UIWebView - initWithRTF on iOS?

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, rtf, nsattributedstring

It is possible to render a `.RTF` file in iOS using a `UIWebView` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258502/rtf-equivalent-to-uiwebviews-loadhtmlstring)). How would one directly 'render' an .RTF file to a custom layer, without depending on `UIWebView`?

I'm displaying a table view with a custom `UITableViewCell`. The cell has the following format:

```
Cell Title
Cell SubTitle
/
|
| Variable length RTF content
|
\
```

The RTF content comes directly from a series of files shipped with the app. Historically, I could convert the RTF to HTML and use a `UIWebView`. With more and more user content and additional functionality to share content between mobile and desktop users, the preferred file format to use is `.RTF`.

On MacOS, you can use `(id)initWithRTF:(NSData *)data documentAttributes:(NSDictionary **)dict` to create a  `NSAttributedString`. What would the equivalent be on iOS? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no stock rich-text view other than `UIWebView`. You'd have to build it yourself or find a third-party tool. I'm not familiar with many RTF parsers for iOS. `UIWebView`, problematic as it can be, is generally you're best approach for this.

Answer (score 4):

OmniGroup has a class for reading and writing RTFs to NSAttributedStrings, but be prepared to transfer *a lot* of dependencies.

https://github.com/omnigroup/OmniGroup/tree/master/Frameworks/OmniUI/iPad/RTF

The NSAttributedStrings can then be drawn with CoreText.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open source [project](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/NSAttributedString-Additions-for-HTML) to create a replacement for the missing `initWithHTML` but, sadly, I have **not** seen anything similar for `initWithRTF`.

Another solution is to parse the RTF yourself - Mono's System.Windows.Forms had such a parser (in C#) but it's not as easy as plug-n-play.