# iOS Objective C: Display RTF document

Tags: ios, rtf

I want to show a RTF document in a view.  This document will be developed in Microsoft Word and will contains images.

What is the best way to do this using standard routines provided?

I would really like sample code to load a RTF document from the bundle.
Kind Regards,
  Jason

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4779065/335858) is an answer to a different question that may be of use to you. The idea is to use `UIWebView`.

Comment: That is a real clash of cultures, because RTF is a proprietary Microsoft standard, and a very old one at that. But why is a Word application saving a document in RTF format? Did someone think it was a good idea?

Comment: Thanks very much for the comments and answers.

Answer (score 20):

UIWebView opens .rtf documents. Try something like

```
NSURL *rtfUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"MyFileName" withExtension:@"rtf"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:rtfUrl];
[_webview loadRequest:request];
```

See the [documentation for UIWebView file types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1630/_index.html).

Comment: Thank you very much.  I'm going to give this a go.

Comment: In my case, I had to change @".rtf" to @"rtf" otherwise URLForResource:withExtension: would return nil.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to do this in Swift instead of Obective-C here's a Swift equivalent of @pmf's answer as a function you can call.

```
func loadRTFDocument() {
    let urlPath =  NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("TermsOfUse", ofType: "rtf")
    let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(urlPath!)
    let request = NSURLRequest.init(URL: url)
    self.webView.loadRequest(request)
}
```