# Import images and text into RTF file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, import, uiimage, rtf

I need to import images and some text into RTF file. Is there any easy way or should I use some finished code/example. Thanks.

Help!

Answer (score 1):

This post explains how you can do it: [iOS Objective C: Display RTF document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501240/ios-objective-c-display-rtf-document)

You can use UIWebView to present different types of documents, such as PDF, DOC, RTF or XLS

Comment: OK, I thought I only needed to see the RTF. If you need to modify a project there can import libraries.

This is the page where they explain everything: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/rich-text-editing-on-ios/

And here are the classes to import: https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText/tree/master/Core/Source

I hope this time will be helpful